# Notification icon(NIIF_INFO, NIIF_WARNING) is not visible in notification in 64bit python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, 64-bit, ctypes

I am using this structure for notifyicondata in python using ctypes

```
class NOTIFYICONDATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint32),
        ('hWnd', HWND),
        ('uID', c_uint32),
        ('uFlags', c_uint32),
        ('uCallbackMessage', c_uint32),
        ('hIcon', c_void_p),
        ('szTip', c_wchar * 128),
        ('dwState', c_uint32),
        ('dwStateMask', c_uint32),
        ('szInfo', c_wchar * 256),
        ('union', _timeout_or_version),
        ('uVersion', c_uint32),
        ('szInfoTitle', c_wchar * 64),
        ('dwInfoFlags', c_uint32),
        ('guidItem', GUID),
        ('hBalloonIcon', c_uint32),
    ]
```

It was working in 32bit python
but NIIF_WARNING or NIIF_INFO icon is not visible in 64bit python
is my structure wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are `uVersion` should be part of the union (union not shown) and the last parameter should be an `HICON`.  Use the pre-defined `ctypes.wintypes` for accuracy.  I added the missing `GUID` type as well.

Since this defines the wide version of the structure, make sure to use the wide version of the `Shell_NotifyIconW` function as well.

```
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

NIF_MESSAGE  = 0x00000001
NIF_ICON     = 0x00000002
NIF_TIP      = 0x00000004
NIF_STATE    = 0x00000008
NIF_INFO     = 0x00000010
NIF_GUID     = 0x00000020
NIF_REALTIME = 0x00000040
NIF_SHOWTIP  = 0x00000080

NIS_HIDDEN     = 0x00000001
NIS_SHAREDICON = 0x00000002

NIIF_NONE = 0x00000000

NIIF_INFO               = 0x00000001
NIIF_WARNING            = 0x00000002
NIIF_ERROR              = 0x00000003
NIIF_USER               = 0x00000004
NIIF_NOSOUND            = 0x00000010
NIIF_LARGE_ICON         = 0x00000020
NIIF_RESPECT_QUIET_TIME = 0x00000080
NIIF_ICON_MASK          = 0x0000000F

class GUID(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Data1', ct.c_ulong),
                ('Data2', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data3', ct.c_ushort),
                ('Data4', ct.c_ubyte * 8))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'GUID(Data1=0x{self.Data1:08x}, Data2=0x{self.Data2:04x}, Data3=0x{self.Data3:04x}, ' \
                    f'Data4=[{", ".join([f"0x{n:02x}" for n in self.Data4])}])'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{{{self.Data1:08x}-{self.Data2:04x}-{self.Data3:04x}-' \
               f'{self.Data4[0]:02x}{self.Data4[1]:02x}-{bytes(self.Data4[2:]).hex()}}}'

    def __init__(self, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4):
        self.Data1 = Data1
        self.Data2 = Data2
        self.Data3 = Data3
        self.Data4[:] = Data4

class U(ct.Union):
    _fields_ = (('uTimeout', w.UINT),
                ('uVersion', w.UINT))

class NOTIFYICONDATAW(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('cbSize', w.DWORD),
                ('hWnd', w.HWND),
                ('uID', w.UINT),
                ('uFlags', w.UINT),
                ('uCallbackMessage', w.UINT),
                ('hIcon', w.HICON),
                ('szTip', w.WCHAR * 128),
                ('dwState', w.DWORD),
                ('dwStateMask', w.DWORD),
                ('szInfo', w.WCHAR * 256),
                ('u', U),
                ('szInfoTitle', w.WCHAR * 64),
                ('dwInfoFlags', w.DWORD),
                ('guidItem', GUID),
                ('hBalloonIcon', w.HICON))
```